# How to populate a file type input field inside a form array in angular?

Tags: angular, forms, formarray

There is a dropdown with four options. For link the link need to be shown and for video,audio and document the choose file button populated with existing file name.push() is working for all fields except source of video, audio and doc. Link is also getting populated but for file type input field i am facing issue.i tried to manipulate css and show the filename using span but not working

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.courseid = history.state;   

    this.apicall.GetEmpCourseDtls(this.courseid).subscribe((res) => {
      this.courseData = res[0];   
         
        // Populate the form controls with the received dataS
        this.courseForm.setValue({
          course:this.courseData.COURSE_ID,
          department: this.courseData.DEPARTMENT,          
          title: this.courseData.TITLE,
          start_date: this.datepipe.transform(this.courseData.START_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
          end_date: this.datepipe.transform(this.courseData.END_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),

          description: this.courseData.DESCRIPTION,
          assessment_status: JSON.stringify(this.courseData.ASSESSMENT_STATUS),
          timeduration: this.courseData.TIME_DURATION,
          Mflag: " ",
          created_by: this.courseData.CREATED_BY,
        TrainingModules:[]
         });

       
      });
      this.apicall.GetEmpMaterialDtls(this.courseid).subscribe((res) => {      
       
         // Populate the training modules
         this.modulesData = res;
          alert(JSON.stringify(res));
          if (this.modulesData && this.modulesData.length > 0) {
            
            this.modulesData.forEach((module:any) => {
              
            let src="";
            if(module.TYPE=="1")
            src= module.SOURCE;
              this.TrainingModules().push(
                this.fb.group({
                  material: module.MATERIAL_NAME,                  
                  type: module.TYPE,
                  source: module.SOURCE,
                  duration: module.TIME_DURATION

                })
            )
              });
            }
          });
        }
```

```html
<td class="path_{{i}}">
                                                  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="trainingModulescon(i).controls['type'].value">
                                                    <!-- Show link for material type '1' (Link)
 -->
                                                    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'1'">
                                                      <!-- <a [href]="trainingModulescon(i).controls['source'].value">{{ trainingModulescon(i).controls['source'].value }}</a> -->
                                                      <input type="text"class="form-control form-control-sm" name="source" formControlName="source" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':
                                                      trainingModulescon(i).controls['source'].errors && (trainingModulescon(i).controls['source'].dirty || trainingModulescon(i).controls['source'].touched)}">
                                                    
                                                    <div *ngFor="let validation of validation_modulemessage.source"  class="invalid-feedback">
                                                        <div  *ngIf="trainingModulescon(i).controls['source'].hasError(validation.type) && (trainingModulescon(i).controls['source'].dirty || trainingModulescon(i).controls['source'].touched)">
                                                        {{ validation.message }} 
                                                        </div> 
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    </ng-container>
                                                    <!-- Show file input and file name for other material types -->
                                                    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
                                                        <input type="file" formControlName="source" name="source" (change)="hideSpan()"[class.hidden]="hideInput">
                                                        
                                                        <span class="source" *ngIf="showSpan">{{ modulesData[i]['SOURCE'] }}</span>
                                                       
                                                                                                                
                                                        
                                                      </ng-container>
                                                      
                                                  </ng-container>
                                                  </td>
```

[![

> enter image description here

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJWP4.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJWP4.png)